# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Tags: javascript, html, xml, button, xhtml

I know this topic has been asked several times as i tried so many times to solve but problem is still there.

**HTML**

```
<button buttontype="normal" name="submitAction" value="myFun" 
         className=""  method="" id="myFun" onclick="javascript:myFun()"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFun(){
    alert("XXXXXXXXX");
}
</script>
```

I want to call *myFun* function but i was getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]` as error in UI.  As i followed stackoverflow solutions some how i am able to remove the error using `html` in place of `javascript` in javaScript Function.

**My Question is :**

1. Why am i not getting the error After modification from `javascript` to `html`
2. Still i am not able to print alert Message.

**update**

```
<report id="1000" name="Reports : Delivery Details" sql="FROM view_sms_status_report" group="Main"
            where="SERVICE_USER_ID=$ServiceUserId"
            filter_list="monthrangefilter_dt"            
            row_comment="0"
            base="0" baseid="0" action_name="commonReport.do"
            param_list="selectedId"
            param_check_list="ServiceUserId" >

    <column name="DUMMY" title="/"  width="5"  count="0" grouptotalall="0" hide="0" type="T" selected="1"
         hide_allow="1" total_allow="0" group_allow="1" grouptotal_allow="0" count_allow="0"  skip_for_sort="1">
         <edit_link> <![CDATA[ <input type="checkbox" name="selectedId" value="$(HSS_PK)"> ]]>  </edit_link>
        </column>

      <report-properties>
            <property name="DUMMY" value="selectedId"/>
      </report-properties>

<buttonlist>
<button buttontype="normal" name="submitAction" value="myFun" 
         className=""  method="" id="myFun" style="font: bold 10px Arial"
         onclick="javascript:myFun()"/>
</buttonlist>   

<javascriptcode>
 <![CDATA[
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFun() {
        alert("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        String[] selectedids = document.getElementById("selectedId");
        alert("*******"+selectedids[0]+"*******");
    }
    </script>
]]>

</javascriptcode>

        <column name="HSS_PK" title="SMS Id"
                width="15"
                count="0" grouptotalall="0"
                hide="0" type="N" selected="1"
                hide_allow="1" total_allow="0"
                group_allow="1" grouptotal_allow="0"
                count_allow="0" />

    <column name="DELIVERY_TIME" title="Delivery time"
                width="8"
                count="0" grouptotalall="0"
                hide="0" type="D" selected="1"
                hide_allow="1" total_allow="0"
                group_allow="1" grouptotal_allow="0"
                count_allow="0" decorator="SimpleDateTimeDecorator" />

    <column name="DELIVERY_STATUS" title="Delivery status"
                width="8"
                count="0" grouptotalall="0"
                hide="0" type="T" selected="1"
                hide_allow="1" total_allow="0"
                group_allow="1" grouptotal_allow="0"
                count_allow="0" />

          <orderby columnlist="HSS_PK DESC" />
        <groupby columnlist="" />
        <sumquery columnlist="" />
    </report>
```

**the whole thing inside a xml file and actually inside file it is like this**

Comment: I think you are missing some relevant code. Can you create a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: given that there's no `]` in your code at all, we can't exactly diagnose the problem.

Comment: the problem is whole thing is in xml file. Where i need to add these function. Initially i was getting the error now i am not getting after modification from `javascript` to `html` but still struggling to print the alert message

Comment: Very minor comment: you don't need `javascript:` at the start of event handlers... the only time you need them are for `<a href="javascript:dothis();">` to differentiate from a URL

Comment: i have updated this with original xml part.

Comment: I can give you the answer. Remove this from on hole and make it active.

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari thanks and will be appreciated.

Comment: @Rohit first of all you have to write correct html for <button>

Comment: @Rohit first of all you have to right correct html for your button <button buttontype="normal" name="submitAction"
         className=""  method="" id="myFun" onclick="javascript:myFun1()">my fun</button> then edit your function name from myFun() to myFun1(), since myFun is the id of your button so it is giving the error. By changing the name of funvtion it will work correctly.

Comment: @PatrickHofman i modified and added the relevant information which is inside my xml. Its a report generator and contains delivery Report information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54051/discussion-between-rohit-and-naveen-chandra-tiwari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your Javascript, where you try to define an object of type `String[]`, which is not a valid Javascript type. Javascript is not Java.

```javascript
function myFun() {
    alert("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    String[] selectedids = document.getElementById("selectedId");
    alert("*******"+selectedids[0]+"*******");
}
</script>
```

In addition, the `getElementById` function doesn't return an array, so you can't use the index `[0]` on its return value.

Solution: replace the `String[]` by `var` and the `selectedids[0]` by `selectedids`.

```javascript
function myFun() {
    alert("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    var selectedids = document.getElementById("selectedId");
    alert("*******"+selectedids+"*******");
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure this does what you want though: it retrieves the element with the literal ID "selectedId". Are you trying to retrieve something the user is clicking on?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to write correct html for your button

```
 <button buttontype="normal" name="submitAction" className="" method="" id="myFun" onclick="javascript:myFun1()">my fun</button>
```

Then edit your function name from myFun() to myFun1(), since myFun is the id of your button so it is giving the error.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFun1(){
    alert("XXXXXXXXX");
  }
 </script>
```

By changing the name of function it will work correctly. You are using the same name as the button id of your function, thats why it is giving the error. You can accept the answer if it works.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean "modification from javascript to html", but I can try to help you print the alert message. A `<button>` is not a self closing tag. It should look more like

```
<button buttontype="normal" name="submitAction" className=""  
    method="" id="myFun" onclick="javascript:myFun()">myFun</button>
```

Also, make sure your javascript function is declared before any code binds it to events. Usually it is placed in the html `<head>` tag to accomplish this.

Next, the CDATA should be placed directly after the `<script`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
  function myFun(){
      alert("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
  }
]]>
</script>
```

so that the contents within `<script` are not parsed as xhtml by the validator.

http://jsfiddle.net/sKYQ6/

Comment: A broken HTML element will not cause a console error. This is right, but it's irrelevant to the error message. PS, javascript runs better at the bottom of the `<body>` tag, not in the head.

Comment: Misplacing the javascript function declaration could cause it not to work. That's what I was hoping to help with.

Comment: @Shredder that would yield an error along the lines of "undefined is not a function"

Comment: @RUJordan So the original error went away, but still not getting alert() message. No new error was given.

Comment: `buttontype` isn't a valid attribute is it? className doesn't need camelCase, not sure why method is stuck on a button element either. ohh and inline js should always be avoided :/ or at the very least advocated against in a comment somewhere. Also, why blindly suggest the OP post the code in the head? If you are posting an answer shouldn't you address the other issues with the code as well?

Comment: @Shredder problem is not related to this as i tried your answer too

Comment: @Rohit Why is it in an xml file? And what do you mean "modification from javascript to html"?

Comment: xml is for message delivery Report and i need to add functions like that. which will also have check box. I added everything but not getting that alert. @Shredder

Comment: @Rohit I made an update. Let me know if it is any help. I don't know what message delivery report is, so sorry I can't be any more help than that.